# Finding the earliest date that a specific event occurred

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to find out whether a user received a coupon within 30 days of the earliest date they entered into a program. Each user can potentially enter into many programs, and I am trying to mark the earliest date for a certain program. This would be some example data:

```
USERID  START_DATE  PROGRAMID COUPON_DATE
  1     2003-02-05   83435    2003-03-01
  1     2004-05-04   83435    2005-03-05
  1     2002-01-30   82222    2001-02-24
  2     2001-02-02   82222    2001-04-22
  2     2000-04-03   22222    2004-12-13
  2     1999-02-05   83435    1999-05-02
  2     2005-05-28   83435    2008-02-02
  3     1998-01-01   24853    1999-02-02
  3     2006-03-02   44533    2006-05-02
```

My desired output would look something like this (for finding whether someone received a coupon within 30 days of entering program 83435):

```
USERID  START_DATE  PROGRAMID COUPON_DATE  MATCH
  1     2003-02-05   83435    2003-03-01     1
  1     2004-05-04   83435    2005-03-05     0
  1     2002-01-30   82222    2001-02-24     0
  2     2001-02-02   82222    2001-04-22     0
  2     2000-04-03   22222    2004-12-13     0
  2     1999-02-05   83435    1999-05-02     0
  2     2005-05-28   83435    2008-02-02     0
  3     1998-01-01   24853    1999-02-02     0
  3     2006-03-02   44533    2006-05-02     0
```

My code thus far is:

```
proc sql;
create table programmatch as
select users.*,
case when (min((start_date) +30) >= coupon_date) then 1
else 0 end as match

from  users
ORDER BY USERID;
quit;
```

This code only marks whether someone received a coupon within 30 days, but I am unsure how to make it mark for a particular programid as well.

Is there a way to do this in proc sql?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Thanks,

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking exactly.  Can you give a more concrete example of how programID factors in?  Right now given userID=1 has the same program but different start dates for the first 2 lines, it isn't obvious to me how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Do you need separate columns for each `PROGRAMID` showing if they got a coupon within 30 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the below query? Not sure whether group by works with case.

```
SELECT USERID, PROGRAMID, CASE when (min((start_date) +30) >= coupon_date) then 1 else 0 end as match
FROM USERS
GROUP BY USERID, PROGRAMID
ORDER BY USERID
```

Please let me know.

Comment: I tried the query, and yes it works in that it groups the program id's together. However, this doesn't do anything about marking for a particular programid as well

Comment: I think the match flag should return a value for a particular program id?

Comment: so far this is marking any case where the user received a coupon within 30 days of their start date, not just the earliest start date.

Answer (score 0):

Why SQL? A data step with first/last processing makes this easy, but it is a hard coded solution based on your program, as any SQL would be as well.

```
proc sort data=have; 
by ID programID start_date coupon_date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id programID;
match=0;
if programID = 83435 
  and first.programID 
  and coupon_date-start_date<=30 
 then match=1;

run;
```